# numpy: arr[True] creates a new axis

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-indexing

I don't understand why True does not behave like a boolean mask:

```
>>> x = np.arange(5)
>>> x[(x<3) & True].shape
(3,)
>>> x[np.repeat(True, 5)].shape
(5,)
>>> x[True].shape
(1, 5)
```

Comment: it doesnt work as a integer because its not an integer, its a boolean

Comment: what are you expecting `& True` to do? the same as `& 1`?

Comment: `x[(x<3) & True]` is the same as `x[x<3]`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I would like to reproduce the behavior of `x[np.repeat(True, 5)]` without having to create an array. I want a common neutral element for boolean elementwise `&` AND binary indexing.

Comment: Odd behavior. It seems to be intentional (see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6104), but I can't understand why.

Comment: And `x[False]` produces (0,5) shape.  `x[np.array(True)]` does same thing as `x[True]`.  I suspect we are dealing with an application of broadcasting rules.  And `x[:,False]` produces (5,0) shape.

Comment: The only relevant thing I can find on the main index doc page is: `the nonzero equivalence for Boolean arrays does not hold for zero dimensional boolean arrays.`